# How to instantiate a list of System.Types from a literal?

Tags: c#, reflection, system.type

I have a few types:

```
public ClassA
{
}

public ClassB
{
}

public ClassC
{
}
```

Now I would like to store some of them in a list?

Some of the failed approaches I've tried:

```
List<System.Type> allowedTypes = new List<System.Type>{ ClassA, ClassC };

List<System.Type> allowedTypes = new List<System.Type>{ System.Type.GetType(ClassA), Systme.Type.GetType(ClassC) };

List<System.Type> allowedTypes = new List<System.Type>{ ClassA.GetType(), ClassC.GetType() };
```

The working approaches I am aware of seem pretty cumbersome:

```
List<System.Type> allowedTypes = new List<System.Type>{ new ClassA().GetType(), new ClassB().GetType() };
```

This approach is cumbersome because it requires `ClassA` and `ClassC` to be specifically prepared for such a use.

```
List<System.Type> allowedTypes = new List<System.Type>{ System.Type.GetType("ClassA"), System.Type.GetType("ClassC") };
```

If there's no way to get rid of these magic strings then well, I guess I should embrace them...

Comment: You are apparently unaware of the `typeof` operator. FYI there is also an operator that turns compile-time names into strings, `nameof`.  So for example you could say `void M(string foo) { if (foo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(foo));` instead of `("foo")`. That way you are dealing with a symbol that is checked for correctness by the compiler, that participates in renaming refactorings, and so on.

Comment: A generalized `typeof` called `infoof` has been proposed for over fifteen years now but never managed to get off the drawing board. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue/ for details.

Answer (score 3):

The correct approach would be the [`typeof` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof):

```
List<System.Type> allowedTypes = 
        new List<System.Type>(){ typeof(ClassA), typeof(ClassC) };
```